# BigQuery SQL Query for top products from the Merchant Center

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-merchant-center

I am running into an issue with writing an SQL query with Google Big Query. Basically looking to transfer the top products, per country, per category which are also in stock into a table.

So far I have pulled in the top products, per country, per category but the issue is with getting the 'in-stock' part added to the table. I can't find any similar keys in the schema to match them up.

Ideally the table would include:

Rank, Product Title, Country, Category, In-Stock

I would really appreciate any help on this! Thanks.

I have tried to add in a separate table that includes the 'availability' key for each product but I could not match it

Comment: Can you provide the schema of your tables ?

Comment: Top products - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/merchant-center-top-products-schema

Comment: Products - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/merchant-center-products-schema

Comment: Product Inventory - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/merchant-center-product-inventory-schema

Answer (score 0):

You have your **top_products** table to check the rank that you can join to the **product_inventory** using the `rank_id`.
This join will retrieve the `product_id` and join that key to the **products** table.
After that, you get the availability information of the product and then you have all the information you require.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you show me an example of the tables being joined?

Comment: ```sql
select rank, product_title.name, ....
from top_products 
left join product_inventory using(rank_id)
left join products using(product_id)
where ...
```

You can filter using `availability_date` or the `availability` column to get your requirements.